# How can I draw this figure?

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw this figure please using LaTeX?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/

Comment: or http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/mesif/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: samcarter  thank you for your response. The problem is how to arrange the nodes into a circular  form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not complete, since I'm not sure if the double-headed arrows, arrows with X marks, etc. are intentional or not. But this is a start, and should be enough to ask more specific questions later:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/
\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\node[draw, circle] (Center) at (0,0) {{Center}};

\foreach \label / \angle in {A/72,B/0,C/288,D/216,E/144}
% https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse15.html
{
  \node[draw, circle] (\label) at (\angle:\radius) {Node $\label$};
}

% http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/
\foreach \source/\target/\bend in {Center/A/bend right, A/Center/bend right} 
    \path[->] (\source) [\bend] edge (\target); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```